# I'm unable to see the mesh anymore. It's turned into a long flat plane

Tags: modeling, mesh

was making a basic mesh and whilst merging some vertices after mirroring my mesh something happened and I'm unable to see the mesh anymore. It's turned into a long flat plane. I can move the single vertex that I can see in the screenshot in any axis (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxHkU.jpg) but if I move it out of that random dark plane I'm unable to see the vertex anymore. Even the default lamp and camera are non-visible when not looked at through the dark plane. I stored a backup mesh in another layer before I mirrored my mesh but the same thing appears on all layers too. Any info would be appreciated, thanks.
[image]

Comment: Some additional pictures showing the modifier stack could help

Comment: Not sure why the mirror modifier isn't showing up but here's a screenshot. (https://imgur.com/a/XaU1e)

Comment: Please make the images visible as part or your post, See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Done. Are the rest of the images needed? I don't want to inconvenience people by posting too many images.

Comment: Yep, the cone clipping solution worked for me too. Thanks for the help, definitely wouldn't have found it on my own :)